# Create guice singleton with gson

Tags: gson, guice

I am trying to create a guice singleton from a json config file.

My singleton is the config:

```
@Singleton
public class QConfig {

    private int port;

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
}
```

I use gson to generate the object:

```
    String content = ...
    QConfig config = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(content, QConfig.class);
```

Is there a way that I can generate the QConfig class myself and still use it a as a singleton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [@Provides](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) method in a guice module :

```
@Provides
public QConfig config() {
    String content = ...
    QConfig config = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(content, QConfig.class);
}
```